# Finding partial strings using str.find() then replace values from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace the values from a column. The values from the column need not to be exact match, so I use str.find(). Once it scanned the string, it should replace the values from the dictionary.

I achieved the desired result for one instance, but I need to do it multiple times.

I tried creating a function but it didn't work. It only worked for the last dictionary value.

```
dictionary  = {"AA" : "111", "BB" : "222", "CC": "333,444"}

#result = []
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    df["renamed"] = np.nan
    df.loc[(df["combined_topic"].str.find(k) != -1), "renamed"] = v
    #result.extend(df["renamed"].to_dict(orient="records"))
```

How should I fix my code? or can you suggest more efficient way to replace multiple values.

Expected output:

```
combined_topic          renamed
AA, harvard                 111
Diliman, Technology, BB     222
Cat, Dog, CC, Bull          333, 444
``
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: I can't fathom what you want to do here. Where are these extra values - harvard, Diliman, Cat etc. coming from, and what is the rule for combining them?

Comment: What should happen if key is _not_ in the topic? keep the topic as it is?

Comment: this is only an example. I have a dataframe from a client that looks like this, I just changed the values. the client have a combined topic column. I need only to replace the values. For 1 cell I need to scan the strings if it contains something from the dictionary, I need to replace it.

Comment: @Chris it will contain NaN. I only need to replace the values that are in the dictionary keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get first matched value of dictionary and then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dict:

```
pat = '|'.join(dictionary)
df['renamed'] = df['combined_topic'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False).map(dictionary)
print (df)
            combined_topic  renamed
0              AA, harvard      111
1  Diliman, Technology, BB      222
2       Cat, Dog, CC, Bull  333,444
```

Your solution houl be used with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), but mainly remove `df["renamed"] = np.nan`, because data are always overwritten in each loop:

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    df.loc[df["combined_topic"].str.contains(k), "renamed"] = v
```

Or:

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    df.loc[(df["combined_topic"].str.find(k) != -1), "renamed"] = v
```

Comment: Wow, the first one is simpler than what I came up and it worked! Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution, too!